# Как сделать правельно переход между страницами через ComboBox в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Перепробовал все событии связанные с Changed. Но все они сначала открывают страницу а потом аж выпадает список с ComboBox.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру

`

```
private void cBPage_IsMouseCapturedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cBPage.Text == "Книги")
            {
                Navigation.startFrame.Navigate(new BookPage());
            }
            if (cBPage.Text == "Поставщики")
            {
                Navigation.startFrame.Navigate(new SupplierPage());
            }
        }
```

`

То есть, когда нажимаем на ComboBox, он сначало открывает страницу ту которая уже в ComboBox стоит в качестве текста, а потом уже выдаёт список.

Как сделать, что бы он переход между страницами делал при выборе из списка, а не при нажатии на ComboBox(что бы он автоматом не открывал страницу, а только при выборе из списка открывал) ?

Comment: Всё, вопрос решён.

Comment: Ну так напишите ответ

Answer (score 0):

Работает, но плохо.

```
private void cBPage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cBPage.Text == "Книги")
        {
            Navigation.startFrame.Navigate(new BookPage());
        }
        if (cBPage.Text == "Поставщики")
        {
            Navigation.startFrame.Navigate(new SupplierPage());
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Что значит плохо? Вы вообще замечали, что в аргументах обработчика события есть какой-то sender, есть какие-то еще Args, интересовались, зачем они нужны?

Comment: Да замечал, но не разу не использовал

Comment: Ну тогда поинтересуйтесь, что содержат внутри `SelectionChangedEventArgs`. Вдруг там есть что-то нужное, чтобы решить вашу задачу.